# i need to update url for larval website where i do try htaccess but not working

Tags: php, laravel, .htaccess, laravel-5, laravel-4

my current website is
`https://example.com/kelimebulucu?harfler=&baslayan=ar&iceren=rt&biten=ma&uzunluk=7` and i need to make it liek

```
https://example.com/kelimebulucu/{baslayan dynamic part}-ile-baslayan-icinde-{iceren dynamic part}-olan-{biten dynamic part}-ile-biten-{uzunluk dynamic part}-harfli-kelimeler
```

i tried with htaccess with tis code

`RewriteRule ^kelimebulucu/([^-]+)-ile-baslayan-icinde-([^-]+)-olan-([^-]+)-ile-biten-([0-9]+)-harfli-kelimeler$ index.php?baslayan=$1&iceren=$2&biten=$3&uzunluk=$4 [NC,L,QSA]`

it's not really work return 404 page. what's the currect way to fix this issue?

this htaccess code i do try but not working

`RewriteRule ^kelimebulucu/([^-]+)-ile-baslayan-icinde-([^-]+)-olan-([^-]+)-ile-biten-([0-9]+)-harfli-kelimeler$ index.php?baslayan=$1&iceren=$2&biten=$3&uzunluk=$4 [NC,L,QSA]`

Comment: You implementation _does_ work, see yourself: https://htaccess.madewithlove.com?share=43a9ed69-e855-469d-baa8-b31659e74210

Comment: If it does not work in your specific setup, then you need to tackle the environment of the test you make. Is that _really_ (really??) the exact URL you request? Did you enable such rewriting in the http server's host configuration using the `AllowOverride` directive? Is that ".htaccess" file really located in the folder configured as the `DOCUMENT_ROOT` of that http host`And is that file really readable for the http server? Is the rewriting module really loaded into the http server?

Comment: A good starting point is to monitor the http server's error log file while making test requests. And remember: always test using a fresh anonymous browser window or make "deep reloads" to prevent looking at previously cached responses.